# CSS in PHP with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have little problem with connection style.php to db

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
   $Color = "#000000";
   $Test = "#555000";
?>
#header {
   background-color: <?php echo $Test; ?>;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
}
a{
    color: <?php echo $Color; ?>;
}
```

this code is working perfectly.
and when i do something like this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
   $Color = "#000000";
   $Test = "#555000";
?>
#header {
   background-color: <?php echo $Test; ?>;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
}
a{
    color: <?php echo $Color; ?>;
}
```

here  #header{} this won't work but a{} will work.
can i somehow make it work?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like hitting the url for both versions directly? It's possible that the db version is outputting something\ BEFORE the css stuff kicks in, so the generated output is `foo#header`, instead of just `#header`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want generate CSS from PHP use it in `.php` file like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
   $Color = "#000000";
   $Test = "#555000";
?>
<style>
#header {
   background-color: <?php echo $Test; ?>;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
}
a{
    color: <?php echo $Color; ?>;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Do not use it in `.css` file. You can also generate new `.css` file from `.php` file with `fopen()` and `fwrite()` PHP functions and then just with meta tag include it into webpage.

**Creating `.css` file from PHP**

```
<?php
$Color = "#000000";
$Test = "#555000";
$css = '#header {
    background-color: '.$Test.';
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
a {
    color: '.$Color.';
}';

$myfile  = fopen("generated_style.css", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); // Open file
fwrite($myfile, $css); // Write CSS
fclose($myfile); // Close file
?>
```

Comment: Hey dave, could you expand (provide a mini example of generating a css file) on your answer?

Comment: Edited answer @GovindRai

Comment: Lovely! Thank you so much! +1